# How much electricity might be expected from simply sinking a 20 foot copper rod or wire vertically into the ground?

Tags: thermoelectricity

Obviously I'm asking about the Seebeck effect.

Assume steel wire for either end.

And the East of England for climate (so likely temperature ranges top & bottom of the thing).

Would something like that even be worthwhile as a "toy"?

Comment: What would you like to achieve with this? What kind of "toy"?

Comment: @Steeven The thing itself is the "toy" as often as not, some people just like to tinker. Honestly I just have a very vague idea right now & I'm having difficulty finding (simply displayed, for someone like me without a suitable technical background) resources for the math etc.

Comment: Sure, but are you interested in measuring a voltage? Or in charging a battery or lighting a LED? If it is suitable will depend on what it is supposed to do. In general, you will need to establish a circuit to see any steady effect. A single rod may only show signs of some effect for a short while. Also, the Seebeck effect is not that large in usual metals. You might see millivolts or less, most likely too little to even detect with regular methods like a multimeter.

Comment: @Steeven Ideally both (charge a battery, light an LED), I suppose the question is more "what sort of depth might you need in the East of England for a sufficient temperature differential between top & bottom of a wire sunk vertically into your lawn to generate a usable charge to charge for an A4 battery with" then?

Comment: The biggest effect with easily obtainable, cheap, and stable metal alloys would probably be nichrome and constantan, not iron and copper. You are unlikely to generate much more than 1mV though, so you would need thousands of them (magically connected somehow to sum the voltages!) to charge a typical A4 battery.

Comment: @alephzero, [Connecting them in series](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Thermopile2.png) will sum the voltages.  The trick is, to keep _all_ of the "hot" junctions hot, and keep all of the "cold" junctions cold.  So, Lots of wires running back and forth between the heat source and the heat sink.

Comment: Man that would be an expensive and boring toy.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the _"heat source"_ is the difference in temperature between the surface & 30' deep (a 10' change after some Googling from the 20' I originally said) which I'm persuaded will be an annual average of a 10 °F temperature difference from the surface.

Answer (score 3):

The temperature difference between the top and bottom of your wire will be small and so will the Seebeck voltage. However, you will probably discover a significant voltage (which will still be small), for an entirely different reason, as follows:

The water contained in wet earth has oxygen from the atmosphere dissolved into it. But the deeper you go into wet earth, the less oxygen you will find dissolved into the water at that depth. In the case of an iron wire going down into wet earth with its one end at the surface and the other end deep, the difference in oxygen concentration in the water present at the ends of the wire will set up an electrochemical cell called an *oxygen concentration cell* which will release iron ions into the wet earth at depth; electrons will flow up the wire and facilitate a redox reaction at the other end of the wire which will consume the electrons.

The cell potential will be of order ~1 volt or so which is sufficient to corrode and eventually perforate the deep end of an iron well bore pipe 1/4 inch thick in ten to fifteen years.

Comment: Water & wet earth etc, I had assumed the wire would be sheathed in plastic & ceramic coats (I should have included that in the original question) so those issues aren't an.. um.. "issue? ~ I've had time to do a bit more Goggling since I originally posted this question & [graphite & aluminium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9Zbmwf5uEQ) it seems are the (most common ? reasonably cheap & readily available) materials that would give best results? ~ depth it seems should be [30 feet](https://www.builditsolar.com/Projects/Cooling/EarthTemperatures.htm) ~ [Continued]

Comment: [Continued] ~ & the average annual temperature would be around 10 °F as it's [close to the average annual temperature for the region where it's located](https://www.wonderopolis.org/wonder/how-cool-are-caves) & with the [average temperatures in England](http://projectbritain.com/weather/average.htm) (because.. gotta pick somewhere) that's around 50 °F which on average is 10 °F different from the surface throughout the year.

Comment: ^ I should probably edit the question & title yes? ~ or should I just post a new one? ~ I suppose what I want to know (now) is really what sort of power a single graphite & aluminium generator cell like this might produce with an (average) 10 °F temperature difference ~ it seems multiple cells in series are an option but I'm also unclear about if the length & thickness of the "wire" used has any impact.

Comment: ^ Obviously I know the temperature differential varies & is greatest in the middle of summer & winter but that just gets too complicated so I went with the average.